# Is it bad to have "missing whitespace"?

Tags: python, syntax, warnings

Is it bad to code like this:

```
list=[a,b,c,d]
for i in range(4):
    var=list[i]
```

As opposed to this?

```
list = [a, b, c, d]
for i in range(4):
    var = list[i]
```

I recently started using PyCharm and it gives me warnings about missing whitespace. Why is it a warning? Is it bad practice?

Comment: That depends on language you are writing, in python would be better if you use whitespaces, just because to be readable your code for other programmers especially if you work with team. Every language has own type style.

Comment: the IDE should also warn you about redefining `list`. Then you should iterate directly on the items instead of creating a range and using indexes....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason that PyCharm is indicating warnings in this case is because PyCharm checks your code-styling according to [PEP 8 Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) and your first example does not follow the rules for ["Whitespace in Expressions and Statements"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id26).

It is good practice to follow styling-guidelines in general because this way there is the possibility to standardise code in order to make it more comprehensible and reusable and maintain code-quality to a prospected level.

I hope that I could answer your question.

Comment: One thing to add is that some teams/workplaces/companies use their own style, which could be directly in contradiction with an "official" one. So, rather than adhering strictly to "official" standards all the time, you might have to adapt to the standards of whatever code base you're working on.